# Facebook criteria to identify the minimal representation of UI state: do we need all of them or just one is enough?

Tags: reactjs

A Facebook article, "Thinking in React", (I don't paste the link simply because I ignore if it's against the rules to post an external link) describes three main criteria that we can use to determine which data inside a UI should be stateful.

These are the criteria or, even better, the questions to make about each piece of data:

1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t
   state.
2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t
   state.
3. Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your
   component? If so, it isn’t state.

Since it's not explicitly expressed in the article, I was wondering if,in your opinion, a piece of data can be part of the state if ALL these questions/points are satisfied or if AT LEAST ONE of these questions/points is satisfied.

Thanks
(please, forgive me for my english, it's not my first language)

Comment: These are just rules of thumb and not carved in stone but if you find yourself answering one or more of these questions with yes it's probably not state. That's how they meant it. So to answer your question: Only one of these is enough. Btw it is not against the rules to [link this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html). In fact it's a part of the official documentation and not an article.

Answer (score 1):

These rules of thumb are, in my experience, very sane - if a piece of data satisfies *any* of them, very likely it isn't a state.

Here are my thoughts on each of these criteria:

> Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state.

One possible exception to this (and it is a stretch) is when the default value of a state is passed via props:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    value: props.defaultValue || ''
  };
}
```

**However**, I think this is a bad practice. This is because the default value would have been set in stone after an instance of the component is created. Instead, a better approach would be to deduce the *actual* value at each render:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    value: ''
  };
}

getValue() {
  return this.state.value || this.props.defaultValue;
}
```

> Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t state.

Well, by definition, state is something that *can* change. Otherwise, it is a constant and should be treated as such.

> Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state.

This is an interesting one. It might be tempting to keep some of the computed values in the state, especially if the aforementioned computation is expensive (e.g., sorting a list, etc). However, what we're doing is *caching* the results of the computation, and that is not the job of the state.

My opinion on this is to re-compute away until you hit some perf issues. When that happens, you can make use of libraries such as [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect). (N.b.: It says it is for Redux, but I'm pretty sure it can be used outside of Redux.)